# Augmented Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the following equality constraint minimization problem:

minimize $\text{ }f(x)$

subject to $Ax=b$

Its Lagrangian is then:

$L(x,y) = f(x) + y^T(Ax-b)$

We can use then **gradient ascent** to solve this problem though it is said that it works with lots of strong assumptions.

Its Augmented Lagrangian is defined as:

$L(x,y)_{\rho} = f(x) + y^T(Ax-b) + \frac{\rho}{2} \|Ax-b \|^2_2$

Then we can use this in the **method of multipliers** (Hestenes, Powell 1969). It is said that this method is designed *to robustify dual ascent*.

Could anyone explain to me the intuition behind Augmented Lagrangian? As far as I can see we are combining penalty function method with Lagrange multiplier. But how does this bring robustness?

**P.S.** Boyd says that *The benefit of including the penalty term is that $g_p$ (dual function associated to the Augmented Lagrangian) can be shown to be differentiable under rather mild conditions on the original problem.*

How does adding extra term help to make the construction "more differentiable"? Or he refers to the fact that, say, when we deal with the L1 or nuclear norms, this extra term allows us to introduce proximal operator?

Comment: What makes you say that $g_p$ is the augmented Lagrangian?  I would guess that what Boyd calls $g_p$ might be the function $g_p(y) = \inf_x L(x,y)_{\rho}$.  Also, I think what you want to say earlier is that we could perhaps use gradient ascent to solve the *dual problem*, but this requires that the dual function be *differentiable*, which is only true under some strong assumptions.

Comment: Concerning the first remark - yes, you are right. Fixed. That's a dual function associated with an Augmented Lagrangian.

Comment: So robustness in this context refers to the differentiability of the dual function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume $f$ is convex.  (I should probably also assume $f$ is closed and proper.)

As you said, the Lagrangian is $L(x,y) = f(x) + \langle y, Ax - b \rangle$.  The dual function is
\begin{align*}
g(y) &= \inf_x \, L(x,y) \\
&= \inf_x \, f(x) - \langle -A^Ty, x \rangle - \langle y, b \rangle \\
&= - \sup_x \, \langle -A^Ty, x \rangle - f(x) + \langle y, b \rangle \\
&= - f^*(-A^T y) - \langle y, b \rangle.
\end{align*}
Here $f^*$ is the convex conjugate of $f$.

The dual problem, expressed as a minimization problem, is 
\begin{equation*}
\text{minimize} \quad f^*(-A^T y) + \langle y, b \rangle.
\end{equation*}

Note that the dual function might not be differentiable!  That is a key point.  To guarantee that $f^*$ is differentiable, we need to assume that $f$ is strictly convex, which is often not the case.  This prevents us (often) from simply solving the dual problem with gradient ascent.

So what can we do if the dual function is not differentiable?  How can we minimize a nondifferentiable function?  One option is to use the *proximal point method*.  The proximal point method does not require the objective function to be differentiable.

If you work out the details, you will find that the augmented Lagrangian method is what you get when you solve the dual problem with the proximal point method.

Vandenberghe's [236c notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html) are a good source for this material.

Comment: Makes sense. But I though that in order to guarantee that $f*$ is differentiable, we need to assume strict convexity of $f$, no? See here for example http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00013-009-0050-3#page-1

Comment: Good point, I modified my answer.  But I think convergence proofs for gradient descent typically assume the objective function is not just differentiable, but also has a Lipschitz continuous gradient.  And to guarantee that $f^*$ is differentiable with a Lipschitz continuous gradient, I think we need to assume that $f$ is strongly convex.

Comment: You definitely are more knowledgeable about the theoretical side of the problem :) I agree about Lipschitz continuous gradient. All the proofs I have read so far relied on this assumption. But I do not know conditions for differentiability of convex conjugate.

Comment: You have related Lagrangian to the proximal point method - fair enough. But how would you relate it to the method of multipliers which does require - correct me if I am wrong - g to be differentiable? Have you see the proof of why Augmented Lagrangian allows $g_p$ to be differentiated under 'mild conditions'?

Comment: One comment: the augmented Lagrangian method and the method of multipliers are two different names for the same method.  Could you give me a link to where Boyd makes the comment about $g_p$ being differentiable under mild conditions?

Comment: http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf, page 11

Comment: I'll bet the "mild condition" is full column rank on $A$. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

As littleO explained above, the rationale behind introducing Lagrangian can be explained via its connection with *proximal point methods*.

Despite the fact that many researchers recommend to refer to D. Bertsekas "Constrained Optimization and Lagrange Multiplier Methods", I personally find it quite unreadable.

This paper provides a fairly good explanation of how Augmented Lagrangian is connected with proximal point methods http://www-2.dc.uba.ar/alio/io/pdf/claio98/paper-2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the differentiability of $g_\rho(y)=\min_x L(x,y)_\rho$, I think that the result is a direct consequence of the Danskin's Theorem (see Proposition B.25 in [Bertsekas, "Nonlinear Programming", 2nd Edition]). More specifically, if $L(\cdot,y)_\rho$ is strictly convex and $L(x,\cdot)_\rho$ is differentiable, then $g_\rho(y)$ is differentiable with $\nabla g_\rho(y)= \nabla_y L(x^\star,y)_\rho$, where $x^\star=\arg\min_x L(x,y)$.